# How to iterate children obtained from ReactDOMRe.domElementToObj?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I'm trying to implement the FLIP animation technique. I have to access the `getBoundingClientRect()` of react's element children.

```rust
let ref = React.useRef(Js.Nullable.null);
```

```js
<div ref={ReactDOMRe.Ref.domRef(ref)}>
  {Belt.List.map(items, item => {
    // ...
  })}
</div>
```

I'm accessing ref content in this way:

```rust
let elMaybe = ref->React.Ref.current->Js.Nullable.toOption;
```

then children of DOM element:

```rust
let children = el->ReactDOMRe.domElementToObj##children;
```

I have a problem with the children. If i use `Js.log(children)`, I see in dev console proper list of children. But `List.length(children)` always returns 2.

This code:

```rust
Belt.List.map(children, child => {
  Js.log(child)
});
```

logs only the first child and `undefined`.

How should I iterate those children? Is there any better way to debug contents of object than Js.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children` is not a `list`, it's an `array`. You won't ever get `list`s from JavaScript, because it doesn't exist as a concept there.

Just use `Array.length` and `Belt.Array.map` instead, then you should be good.

See the Reason documentation on [List & Array](https://reasonml.github.io/docs/en/list-and-array) for more details.